# LowLevelKeyboardProc is not called upon PeekMessage call when window has focus

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to filter some keys in a program. I am using the `LowLevelKeyboardProc` callback.

Here is part of the code:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(INT nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION)  // do not process message 
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    auto p = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);

    switch (wParam)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            {
                if (((p->vkCode == VK_LWIN) || (p->vkCode == VK_RWIN)))
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (p->vkCode == VK_ESCAPE && p->flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I have the callback registered like this:

```cpp
static LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    static HHOOK hook_keys;
    
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hook_keys = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), 0);
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When I create a new sample C++ project, the code works just fine. But, I have quite a huge codebase, where the `PeekMessage()` and `GetMessage()` functions are called multiple times. The callback is firing, only when window is not active, but PeekMessage is called in Update every frame, but hook is not fired.

I tried to read all the documentation available, but haven't found anything that would help me. There is no other `KeyboardProc` or `LowLevelKeyboardProc` function in the code.

Do you guys have any idea what could cause this?

I also found out that at the end of the `WndProc()` function, where it is calling `return DefWindowProc()`, might this be a problem?

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? It's possible that your application checks the state of keys directly. It's worth to note that [the Keyboard callback is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc#remarks).

Comment: I did some more digging and I found out that my question was a little missleading. It is actually not called "late" as I stated, but it is called just when the window is OUT of focus, which is kind of ironic. I checked that the PeekMessage is called even if the window IS active, but the hook is not called, it seems like the message is not dispatched in the PeekMessage, but since it is winapi code I cannot be sure.
The PeekMessage is called every frame in Update.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by checking state of the keys? I think the answer is yes, but depends what you mean.

There is a code like this for example.

`case WM_SYSCHAR: // Prevent ALT + key combinations from creating 'ding' sounds
{
 const bool bAlt = (msgParams.lParam & (1 << 29)) != 0;
 if (bAlt && msgParams.wParam == VK_F4)
 {
  return false; // Pass though ALT+F4
 }
 msgResult.lResult = 0;
 return true;
}`

This is called in WndProc, or more specifically in inner function that is called from WndProc

Comment: Btw If I read it correctly, the hook should be global, that means should be called for all the threads, if last parameter of SetWindowsHookExW (dwThreadId) is 0.
From docs: "if this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? I haven't reproduced it.